# PeoplePicker not providing all user info, only display name

Tags: javascript, clientpeoplepicker

I have a PeoplePicker that I want to use for an email destination. There is no problem entering a user and having it resolve, but the only info I can retrieve from the picker is display name. I expect to get the AutoFillKey (where I can get the user's login name), EntityData for more properties, etc. What I get is a barebones object:

```
{
  AutoFillDisplayText: "Last, First",
  DisplayText: "Last, First",
  EntityType: "User",
  IsResolved: True,
  Resolved: True
}
```

Do I need to configure the picker a certain way to get all the values?

My config is:

```
var schema = {};
schema["PrincipalAccountType"] = "User";//,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema["SearchPrincipalSource"] = 15;
schema["ResolvePrincipalSource"] = 15;
schema["AllowMultipleValues"] = false;
schema["MaximumEntitySuggestions"] = 50;
SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(pickerDOM, null, schema);
```

**Update 7/21/17**

I think my real issue is populating the PeoplePicker from a user I retrieve from a custom list. If the end user picks a person, I can retrieve the full user info object. If I retrieve a person from a person field in a list, it doesn't retrieve the rest of the fields, it only stores the info I give it.

So, my question should really be - how do I get a list item that includes a person field so I can have the PeoplePicker populate completely? Is there a way to specify the person in the picker and trigger a "resolve" method that looks up the rest of the info and binds it to the picker?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create your own PeoplePicker. You can have a look at some extended code about it on my Gist: https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/5925efc9f4fecccc40612c6a5db7efc9 ... By just looking at what you have shared here, I don't see what could be wrong. But try to look at the Gist and maybe you'll see something that you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

The following JavaScript will retrieve complete user details.

```
var peoplePickerId = "supervisorPeoplePicker";
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerId + "_TopSpan"];
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
if(users.length > 0) {
    console.log("loginName:" + users[0].Key);
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I expect to get. Instead, I get only what I posted in the question.